# How to do User Input Error Handling in Python?

Tags: python, user-input

I don't know why I never thought of this before... but I'm wondering if there's a neater/shorter/more efficient manner of error handling a user input.  For example, if I ask the user to enter either "hello" or "goodbye", and they type something else, I need it to tell the user it's wrong and ask again.

For all of coding I've ever done, this is how I've done it (typically the question is better):

```
choice = raw_input("hello, goodbye, hey, or laters? ") 

while choice not in ("hello","goodbye","hey","laters"):

   print "You typed something wrong!"

   choice = raw_input("hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? ")
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this? Or should I just stick with how I've had it?  This is the method I use for all languages I've written in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple script, the way you have it is fine.

For a more complex system, you're effectivey writing your own parser.

```
def get_choice(choices):
  choice = ""
  while choice not in choices:
      choice = raw_input("Choose one of [%s]:" % ", ".join(choices))
  return choice

choice = get_choice(["hello", "goodbye", "hey", "laters"])
```

Comment: I like this because it is general, and the prompt is auto generated based on the choices.  My only criticism would be I would do `",".join(choices)` instead of `" ".join(choices)`.  And I would also do `while choice not in choices:`

Comment: Hmm. I can see creating a method being cleaner, but I feel like the only way I'd prefer it is if I passed a function to it so I could use the method for every question I asked.  That would definitely be convenient, just... it might take me a little while to figure out and replace lol

Comment: As in, I have a lot of user inputs, so I'd rather not have a new method for each one

Comment: @user2869231 "I have a lot of user inputs" -- that's the best time to have a general method! :)

Comment: @user2869231 This is a general method, so you wouldn't need a new method for each.  If you are concerned about the prompt message, you can add an additional string as a parameter that could be the prompt message.

Comment: aha! that's what it would be.  I don't know why I was thinking I needed to send a method in... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your code to always enter the `while` loop, you only have to have the `raw_input` on one line.

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input("hello, goodbye, hey, or laters? ")
    if choice in ("hello","goodbye","hey","laters"):
        break
    else:
        print "You typed something wrong!"
```

Comment: That's true. It might make things a little prettier not having the second input line in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with recursion

```
>>> possible = ["hello","goodbye","hey"]
>>> def ask():
...     choice = raw_input("hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? ")
...     if not choice in possible:
...         return ask()
...     return choice
... 
>>> ask()
hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? d
hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? d
hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? d
hello,goodbye,hey,or laters? hello
'hello'
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't this run the risk of reaching the max recursion limit if the user doesn't know how to type the correct input?

Comment: yeah thats why usualy you let the user know.

Comment: it also seems like it would be counter-productive; making it longer and more complicated lol

Comment: you have 2 choises either recursion or while True, i personaly prefer recursion.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you do it.
Having the options in a list might be prettier though depending on how you're using it.

```
options = ["hello", "goodbye", "hey", "laters"]
while choice not in options:
    print "You typed something wrong!"
```

Comment: Don't think it is particularly "prettier", but I guess that is a matter of taste. I do like that you construct the list/tuple only once, though.

Comment: @Jblasco It depends heavily on the amount of options.

Comment: Sorry, @Mattias, completely misread your answer! I thought you meant to say that a list would be prettier than a tuple! Then, just to make things more complicated, I went and said that I do like that you separated the options... xD